# Typescript interface with generic methods

Tags: typescript

**Is it possible to have interface in Typescript with generic methods that will allow us to tell that T type will extend some other type?**

```
interface Abc {
  a: string;
  b: string;
  c: string;
}
interface Checkout {
  onComplete<T>(session: T): void
}
class StripeCheckout implements Checkout {
  onComplete<T extends Abc>(abc: T) {
    console.log(abc.a);
  }
}
```

onComplete method is invalid

```
Property 'onComplete' in type 'StripeCheckout' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'Checkout'.
  Type '<T extends Abc>(session: T) => void' is not assignable to type '<T>(session: T) => void'.
    Types of parameters 'session' and 'session' are incompatible.
      Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'Abc'.(2416)
```

Solution #1 (generic interface which will force us to tell types at the class level):

```
interface Abc {
  a: string;
  b: string;
  c: string;
}
interface Checkout<T> {
  onComplete(session: T): void
}
class StripeCheckout implements Checkout<Abc> {
  onComplete(session: Abc) {
    console.log(session);
  }
}
```

Problem is that if I will have more generic methods with different types it will look something like this `Abc<T, U, V, Z>`. We could fix that with multiple interfaces, however I'd like to tell Typescript about generic method type when I define method in class.

Solution #2 ("generic" with any):

```
interface Abc {
  a: string;
  b: string;
  c: string;
}
interface Checkout {
  onComplete(session: any): void
}
class StripeCheckout implements Checkout {
  onComplete(session: Abc) {
    console.log(session);
  }
}
```

Example usage:

```
const checkout = new StripeCheckout();
checkout.onComplete({a: '1', b: '2', c: '3'})
```

Comment: What is wrong with `Checkout<A, B, C, D>` where A,B,C,D are arguments of extended methods?

Comment: You should define constraint on interface level, otherwise you're breaking substitution principle

Answer (score 2):

TypeScript, and many other languages will not allow you to do this, I would suggest the first solution.

```ts
interface Abc {
    a: string;
    b: string;
    c: string;
}
interface Default {
    a: number;
}
interface Checkout<T, A=Default> {
    onComplete(session: T): void;
    otherFunction(input: A) : void;
}
class StripeCheckout implements Checkout<Abc> {
    otherFunction(input: Default) {
        throw new Error("Method not implemented.");
    }
    onComplete(session: Abc) {
        console.log(session);
    }
}
```

Why? Because this way you can set limitations on your generics on the `Checkout` interface, giving you more control. Your interface should define the contract, not the class implementing it.